# Wordpress not filtering/sorting categories

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I had a custom wordpress theme done but now can't get hold of the original person who did it.

The all categories are showing on the all category pages, although I have made a new category and moved 2 posts in to it. (just attempting to create an archive)

Could any of you kind people point me in the direction of what I need to be looking for in the category.php page please? (see below)

```
<?php if ( is_day() ) : ?>
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Daily Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'your-theme' ), get_the_time(get_option('date_format')) ) ?></h1>

<?php elseif ( is_month() ) : ?>
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Monthly Archives:<span>

<?php $archive_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1000');
            while ($archive_query->have_posts()) : $archive_query->the_post(); ?>

                  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">


            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
             </div>

                    <div class="span5">

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( __('Permalink to %s', 'your-theme'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <div class="entry-summary">  
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">
                </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

            </div><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
             </div>
                              </div>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I had top remove some code as it wouldn't let me past it in, which isn't filling me with confidence tbh.

I'm not a Wordpress aficionado but know the basics (I think)

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is expected from your code. Never use custom queries on archive pages. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query instead.

Comment: I assume that would be the part beginning 

<?php $archive_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1000');

I just can't seem to get the news category to only show the news posts (it shows every post irrespective of category)

Is this the 'custom queries' causing this?

Comment: Correct :-). Just remember to remove the `$archive_query->` part from the loop as well

Comment: Would this be correct then?

<?php $pre_get_posts = new WP_Query('showposts=1000');
    while ($pre_get_posts->have_posts()) : $pre_get_posts->the_post(); ?>

Comment: It still shows all posts? Apologies, I appear to know much less that I thought

Comment: No, doing it completely wrong. :-) I will post an answer to guide you

Answer (score 0):

You should never replace the main query on archive pages or the home page with a custom query, you will always run into some kind of issue as you have experienced now :-)

To rectify your problem, delete this part

```
<?php
$archive_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1000'); 

while ($archive_query->have_posts()) : 
    $archive_query->the_post(); ?>
```

And replace it with

```
<?php
while(have_posts()) :
    the_post();
```

You should now see the correct posts showing up

If you need to change something in the main query, do it with `pre_get_posts`. Lets take your example code. You need to change `posts_per_page` to 1000 on all archive pages, then you can do the following in your `functions.php`

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($q) {

    if (!is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_archive()) {
        $q->set('posts_per_page', 1000);
    }

});
```

Just make sure, the above code need php 5.3+

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try this later and let you know how I get on. Much appreciated ;-)

Comment: No problem, take your time. :-)

Comment: Pieter, you are a scholar and a gentleman. Worked perfectly. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Any reason why this question is still open :-)